# Which countries can receive payments from Apple?

Tags: app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

I'm from Costa Rica and I don't know if I can use In App Purchases in the iOS apps I'm developing.
Does Apple have a list of countries for which this functionality is available?

Comment: If you're a registered iOS developer, Apple has more documentation about app purchases and IAP's than you can ever read. Look thru the Apple Developer sites, all the info is there.

Answer (score 1):

In-App Purchases are the same as the sale of an app, from the perspective of where they can be made available.

Apple has a list: [App Store Territories](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/AppStoreTerritories.html)